# i have an error after deploying my nodejs app on heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, heroku

I deployed my nodejs app with heroku, im getting errors when i try to open it on the browser

So i already checked my package.json with the start script i already setted node env and production aswell, i checked the model (one of the error points to that on the log), im not sure what it is

```
2019-07-09T02:50:24.457773+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-07-09T02:50:24.385238+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:613
2019-07-09T02:50:24.385263+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2019-07-09T02:50:24.385266+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-07-09T02:50:24.385267+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-07-09T02:50:24.385270+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '../models/user'
2019-07-09T02:50:24.385272+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2019-07-09T02:50:24.385274+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/routes/index.js
2019-07-09T02:50:24.385276+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/app.js
2019-07-09T02:50:24.385279+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:610:15)
2019-07-09T02:50:24.385281+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:526:27)
2019-07-09T02:50:24.385368+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:19)
2019-07-09T02:50:24.385373+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
2019-07-09T02:50:24.385375+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/routes/index.js:3:14)
2019-07-09T02:50:24.385377+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:759:30)
2019-07-09T02:50:24.385379+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:770:10)
2019-07-09T02:50:24.385381+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628:32)
2019-07-09T02:50:24.385383+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:555:12)
2019-07-09T02:50:24.385385+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:19)
2019-07-09T02:50:24.438626+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

link to the github repo
https://github.com/ArielBailon/b--learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call:

```
require('../models/user')
```

but your file is `User.js`

You can choose:

- Rename `User.js` to `user.js`
- Use `require('../models/User')` instead of `require('../models/user')`

Comment: that was so weird, i swear i changed it to user.js and still problem but now i tried just changing the require to User.js, that worked thanks a lot

Comment: Because you forgot use `git mv ....`, this error was take a little my time